# Add body class if a block is present

Tags: 8, theming

I need to add a body class if a block or menu is present on the current page on Drupal 8. Probably this should be done on `template_preprocess_page()` or `template_preprocess_html()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A block is visible in a page depending on two conditions:

- None of the condition plugins associated to the block marks the block as not visible
- The current user has the permission to see the block

Assuming the block is visible at a specific path is wrong because the current user could simply not have the permission to view it. Adding to that the fact that any third-party modules could define new condition plugins, the only way to avoid duplicating in code the block settings done from the user interface is using code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Replace 'block_id' with the ID of your block.
  $block = Block::load('block_id');
  if ($block && $block->access('view')) {
    // The block is visible to the current user.
    // Replace 'the-class-to-add' with your CSS class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'the-class-to-add';
  }
}
```

Remember to add the correct `use` statements on the top of the file containing that code (e.g. `use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;` to be able to access the block entity class).

Comment: How do I get the block id? I presume it's the ID rendered in the DOM, but when I try to use your code I can't get it to work. It does work when I bypass the if statement.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work as I was hoping with a View block. This code successfully identified pages where the block had been placed in Block Layout, and added the body class to those pages, but the class was present even when there was no content in the view block and the block wasn't rendered. So, unfortunately, I couldn't make use of the body class.

Answer (score 2):

You can only add classes to the body tag in template_preprocess_html() hooks. Blocks are only built in page.html.twig, so they are not yet visible here. But blocks have visibility condition, and you should use that condition here, for example the path.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  if ($current_path == 'path/where/block/appears') {
    $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'class-name';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, both answers are right, but while I was trying @kiamlaluno suggestion I realized the block didn't had any condition setup since it was a menu block, so it's always enabled.

I ended up checking if the current page is a children of the menu block I want to target.

```
$menu_tree = Drupal::menuTree();
$parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters('main');
$parameters->setTopLevelOnly();
$main_menu_top_level = $menu_tree->load('main', $parameters);  

foreach ($main_menu_top_level as $sub_tree) {
  if($sub_tree->inActiveTrail){
    $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class-here';
  }
}
```